# Skip next 12 hours of recorded for the same user in recorded listing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list like below image

[image]

In the above list, we have 4 entries of user_id 14

```
14:2018-09-26 06:09:18
14:2018-09-26 05:50:01
14:2018-09-25 14:29:27
14:2018-09-25 14:16:34
```

My concern is I need to skip next 12 hours record from the current record for the same user_id
EX: For user_id 14 only 2 records need to be fetched for the list like below

```
14:2018-09-26 06:09:18
14:2018-09-25 14:29:27
```

`14:2018-09-26 05:50:01` records is not in the result set because it's in 12 hours of `14:2018-09-26 06:09:18`

Same for all other users.

I have checked Nick's query but it's also not as per my requirement. Please check  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da3f46/1/0).

As per Nick's query, It shows only two record

```
14  2018-09-26T23:09:56Z
14  2018-09-25T14:29:27Z
```

But as per my requirement, I need three records

```
14  2018-09-26T23:09:56Z
14  2018-09-26T06:50:56Z
14  2018-09-25T14:29:27Z
```

Because we need to skip record's till 2018-09-26T11:09:56Z for the 2018-09-26T23:09:56Z record

Comment: MySql 7.x or 8.x ?  I ask this because in version 8.0 you can use the window functions, but not in 7.5.

Comment: Server version: 5.6.35-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select @idLag := 0, @dtLag := cast('2018-01-01' as datetime);
select user_id, created from (
    select case when (@idLag = user_id and timestampdiff(hour, created, @dtLag) >= 12) or @idLag <> user_id then user_id else null end user_id,
                 created,
                 @idLag := user_id,
                 @dtLag := created
    from my_table
    order by created desc
)a where user_id is not null
```

Comment: my data contains data for "2017,2016,2015 and so on... So what to do in this case.

Comment: Yes, it's working now I will try to combine it with my query because it's a very complicated query. I have to join around 10 tables for the complex algorithm.

Comment: @Rav'sPatel If the naswer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: Still, some issues are there. Please check entries with id 964, 10, 982 in this sqlFiddel "http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6a669/2/1"

Answer (score 2):

This query should do what you want. It joins your `user_times` table to itself where the time is within 12 hours later than the previous time. If there is no such time, then the value is output. Here is a short test case based on your sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_times;
CREATE TABLE user_times (user_id INT, created DATETIME);
INSERT INTO user_times VALUES
(14, '2018-09-26 06:09:18'),
(14, '2018-09-26 05:50:01'),
(14, '2018-09-25 14:29:27'),
(14, '2018-09-25 14:16:34');
SELECT u1.*
FROM user_times u1
LEFT JOIN user_times u2 ON u2.user_id = u1.user_id AND
          u2.created BETWEEN u1.created + INTERVAL 1 SECOND AND u1.created + INTERVAL 12 HOUR
WHERE u2.user_id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
user_id     created
14          26.09.2018 06:09:18
14          25.09.2018 14:29:27
```

Comment: @Rav'sPatel as I understand your requirement, we shouldn't show any record that is within 12 hours of the next record for that user. In that case the record of `06:50:56` shouldn't be shown because it is within 12 hours of `11:09:56`

Comment: No, It's not like that. We need check 12 hours interval from the first record of the user. Ex. We have got 2018-09-26 23:09:56 first record with user_id 14 so we need to check 12 hours of an interval from 2018-09-26 23:09:56. So the interval between 2018-09-26 23:09:56 and 26.09.2018 06:09:18 is more than 12 so we also need "26.09.2018 06:09:18" in the list.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Have you tried @MichalTurczyn answer? I think that is how it works

Comment: I haven't tried it. Because he created constant @dtLag but it's not possible in my case. I have lots of data from the last few years and with a very complex algorithm.

Comment: Why is it not possible to create constants?

Comment: He defines date "2018-01-01" but my data contains data for "2017,2016,2015 and so on...

Comment: That's ok you can just change that value to something earlier than the first date in your database e.g. 1900-01-01

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick, it joins the table on itself with two conditions, being the same user id and the 12 hour interval in your times, then it is easily queryable.

```
SELECT yt1.*
FROM yourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN yourTable yt2 ON yt2.user_id = yt1.user_id AND
          yt2.created BETWEEN yt1.created + INTERVAL 1 SECOND AND yt1.created + INTERVAL 12 HOUR
WHERE yt2.user_id IS NULL
AND yt1.user_id = 14
```

---

Here is a working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b04/4

and DDL script for the eventuality of the fiddle link breaking:

```
create table temp(user_id int, created datetime);

insert into temp values (982, '2018-09-26 07:09:56');
insert into temp values (964, '2018-09-26 06:58:56');
insert into temp values (14,  '2018-09-26 06:09:56');
insert into temp values (14,  '2018-09-26 05:50:56');
insert into temp values (964, '2018-09-26 05:09:56');
insert into temp values (29,  '2018-09-26 05:01:56');
insert into temp values (596, '2018-09-26 04:50:42');

insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-25 21:42:05');
insert into temp values (20,  '2018-09-25 16:11:58');
insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-25 15:12:13');
insert into temp values (14,  '2018-09-25 14:29:27');
insert into temp values (14,  '2018-09-25 14:16:34');
insert into temp values (596, '2018-09-25 14:00:16');
insert into temp values (964, '2018-09-25 13:23:42');
insert into temp values (982, '2018-09-25 13:15:00');
insert into temp values (964, '2018-09-25 13:13:22');
insert into temp values (964, '2018-09-25 12:58:27');
insert into temp values (982, '2018-09-25 09:47:01');
insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-25 06:38:32');

insert into temp values (11,  '2018-09-24 18:05:16');
insert into temp values (11,  '2018-09-24 16:13:39');
insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-24 14:15:50');
insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-24 14:15:23');
insert into temp values (10,  '2018-09-24 14:09:49');
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of my answer!

Comment: @Nick i did not see your answer before i posted mine

Comment: I have checked your query but still, there is some issue with this. Please check my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d591c/3/0. In this the result is wrong only two records are there but As per my requirement, It needs to be 3. Please check my edits in question

Comment: @Rav'sPatel what issue do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use the lag function to compare against the previous row and add a column for the hours difference between the two.

You can then select, from that table, only rows where the hours difference is greater than or equal to 12.